# bash: ls: command not found

Tags: bash, debian, shell, command-line

I'm using VMWare, and running debian and whenever I run a new terminal my commands like "ls" seem to be lost.

I've tried the solutions listed here for instance: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/22859/bash-ls-command-not-found

When I do:

```
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin
```

it works temporarily.

When I do:

```
cd ~
nano .bash_profile
export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:$PATH
```

-- the file changes and the save reflects but when I open a new terminal the commands are forgotten again.

Edit:

```
rowen@debianRhys:~$ echo $PATH 
/home/rowen/bin:PATH


source .bash_profile
bash: dircolors: command not found
```

Comment: By "When I do...", you mean you follow the actual instructions of the answer, is this correct? Because the part you quoted here is **not** the same as the answer. If you did follow those instructions, it may be that the profile file is not ".bash_profile" but possibly ".bashrc". Or even ".profile" if your shell is not actually bash.

Comment: Yes, I follow the instructions, putting that line of code into .bash_profile with nano and then saving it. It says bash: ls: command not found, so I figure it is bash. So should I try edit all of those files with that line?

Comment: Open a new terminal and run `echo "$PATH"`. Run `source .bash_profile` and check again. Edit your question and add the output. Also try to add it to `.bashrc` instead.

Comment: I tried as you said, editing .bashrc. I added the line to the top of the code. There's actually code in this file though as opposed to the '.bash_profile'.

I noticed it has these 3 lines at the bottom: 
'PATH=~/bin:PATH
PATH=~/bin:PATH
PATH=~/bin:PATH'

Comment: It is clear from your update that you have added the word `PATH` at the end of the shell's search path.  This is likely due to a forgotten `$`. Double check your `.bash_profile` file. In a previous comment, you mention `PATH=~/bin:PATH` (etc.).  This should _definitely_ be `PATH=~/bin:$PATH`.

Comment: Ah thank you! You are a life saver. Thank you to everyone for all your help.

Answer (score 2):

From comments it was made clear that the user had one or several lines in their `~/.bash_profile` file saying

```bsh
PATH=~/bin:PATH
```

This would clear the `PATH` variable, resetting it to a list of paths that are not generally useful.

This would easily be remedied ty prefixing `PATH` with `$` in the value assigned to the `PATH` variable:

```bsh
PATH=~/bin:$PATH
```

This prepends `~/bin` to the value of `$PATH`, rather than discarding the old value completely.

Comment: I had added `PATH=xyz/...` in my `.env` file and wondered why I could not use `ls` right after running `source .env`. Clearly because I destroyed my PATH variable, and it was back as soon as I reopened my shell. ;)